# making approve button

Tags: python, odoo

i'm newbie in Python and openerp. I have a problem when I want to make a simple approve button to change the state, only to change the status.

error message : *No handler found.*

this is my script :

XML:

```
<button name="approve" states="draft" string="Approve" type="object"/>
```

python:

```
...
class student(osv.osv):
    _name = "sim.student"
    _description = "Data Siswa"

    def approve(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        """ 
        confirm one or more order line, update order status and create new cashmove 
        """
        #cashmove_ref = self.pool.get('lunch.cashmove')
        orders_ref = self.pool.get('sim.student')
        for order_line in orders_ref.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            if order_line.status != 'confirmed':

                #cashmove_ref.create(cr, uid, values, context=context)
                order_line.write({'status': 'confirmed'}, context=context)
        return order_line.create(cr, uid, ids, context=context)

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `order_line` is a Browseable object, not a Model, and the `write()` should be done on a Model object.

Instead of:

```
order_line.write({'status': 'confirmed'}, context=context)
```

try:

```
orders_ref.write(cr, uid, order_line.id, {'status': 'confirmed'}, context=context)
```

Comment: Your error message doesn't help much. My advice is to remove things until you stop getting an error. That will help you to pin down your (first) cause for errors. I would start by commenting out the `approve()` contents.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is because of the `create()` function called at the return of the function. You just need to `return True`. Also the create function doesn't have ids as argument. You need to pass dictionaries containing fields and values needed for the student record. If you are trying to copy the current student record, use the copy() function.